# Android : How can I cache the tweets that I’ve got using the Fabric SDK for offline mode?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I'm getting started with the Fabric SDK and I've been trying to cache the tweets to the android device, when the user is offline and has no network connectivity after the user has once seen the list of tweets.

I'm using the client.getSearchService().tweets(....) method to retrieve my tweets and I'm getting the response as a List of `com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet` objects as in Retrofit.

I'm trying to write these tweets to a file my internal storage but since Tweet model isn't serializable and therefore I'm not able to store it. Is there a way that I can get a JSON response from the Fabric SDK? I'm looking for a service similar to `client.URLRequestWithMethod(...)` on iOS Fabric SDK.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you just serialize it with google [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) ?

Comment: Or convert tht Tweet object in json and store in SQLIte database?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by, using a Custom Service and client for doing the search to get a JSON response instead of using retrofit's mapping.

For example, for the Search Service,

```
interface CustomSearchService {
    @GET("/1.1/search/tweets.json")
    void tweets(@Query("q") String var1, @EncodedQuery("geocode") Geocode var2, @Query("lang") String var3, @Query("locale") String var4, @Query("result_type") String var5, @Query("count") Integer var6, @Query("until") String var7, @Query("since_id") Long var8, @Query("max_id") Long var9, @Query("include_entities") Boolean var10, Callback<Response> var11);
}

static class SearchApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {

    public SearchApiClient(Session session) {
        super(session);
    }

    public CustomSearchService getCustomSearchService() {
        return getService(CustomSearchService.class);
    }
}
```

and obtaining the data through,

```
apiClient.getCustomSearchService().tweets(searchParam.toString(), null, null, null, null, TWEET_COUNT, null,null, null, true,
        new Callback<Response>() {

 @Override
 public void success(Result<Response> result) {

       //DO SOMETHING WITH THE JSON RESPONSE HERE
       // InputStream stream = result.data.getBody().in(); //<-- This contains the data

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has support for custom OkHttp Clients, check out their example app:

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/samples/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/SampleApplication.java

I've attached a relevant snippet:

```
    final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY,
            BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);

    final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Twitter(authConfig))
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .debuggable(true)
            .build();

    Fabric.with(fabric);

    final HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    final OkHttpClient customClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build();

    final TwitterSession activeSession = TwitterCore.getInstance()
            .getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

    final TwitterApiClient customApiClient;
    if (activeSession != null) {
        customApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(activeSession, customClient);
        TwitterCore.getInstance().addApiClient(activeSession, customApiClient);
    } else {
        customApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(customClient);
        TwitterCore.getInstance().addGuestApiClient(customApiClient);
    }
```